# ¿Cómo transponer datos en R?

Tags: r, r-dplyr, reshape

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
id = c(ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005167, ES150010005167, ES150010005167, ES150010005168)
días = c(1820, 1820, 1820, 1820, 2223, 2223, 2223, 1691)
año = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2007)
prod = c(129, 156, 157, 172, 186, 167, 218, 116 )
cría = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
tcambio = c(405, 730, 1093, 1460, 727, 1145, 1498, 407)

datos <- as.data.frame (id, días, año, producción, cría, tiempo_cambio)
```

datos

```
id              días  año  cría   prod       tcambio
ES150010005163  1820  2007  1     129          405
ES150010005163  1820  2008  1     156          730
ES150010005163  1820  2009  2     157         1093
ES150010005163  1820  2010  1     172         1460
ES150010005167  2223  2008  1     186          727
ES150010005167  2223  2009  1     167         1145
ES150010005167  2223  2010  1     218         1498
ES150010005168  1691  2007  1     116          407
```

Busco transponer los datos para que el resultado final sea algo cómo

```
id = c(ES150010005163, ES150010005167, ES150010005168)
días = c(1820, 2223, 1691)
año = c(2007, 2008, 2009)
cría = c(1, 1, 1)
prod = c(129, 186, 116)
tcambio = c(405, 727, 407)
año2 = c(2008, 2008)
cria2 = c(1, 1)
prod2 = c(156, 186)
tcambio2 = c(730, 727)
año3 = c(2009, 2009)
cria3= c(2,1)
prod3= c(157, 167)
tcambio3=c(1093, 1145)
año3= c(2009, 2009)
cria4= c(2,1)
prod4=c(172, 218)
tcambio4=c(1460,1498)

id             días  año  cría  prod tcambio año2 cria2 prod2 tcambio2 año3 cria3 prod3 tcmabio3 año4 cría4 prod4 tcambio4
ES150010005163 1820  2007  1    129  405     2008  1    156    730     2009  2     157   1093     2009 2     157   1460
ES150010005167 2223  2008  1    186  727     2008  1    186    727     2009  1     167   1145     2009 1     167   1498
ES150010005168 1691  2007  1    116  407     ... etc
```

He intentado usando reshape, pero no sé definir "**timevar**" para que haga lo que necesito.

He usado:

```
prueba2 <- reshape(datos, timevar = "camparto",
        idvar = c("crotal","padre","DVP","cens"),
        direction = "wide")
```

y obtengo el resultado:

```
id = c(ES150010005163, ES150010005167, ES150010005168)
días = c(1820, 2223, 1691)

cría.2007 = c(1, "NA", 1)
prod.2007 = c(129, "NA", 116)
tcambio.2007 = c(405, "NA", 407)


id              dias   cria.2007 prod.2007 tcambio.2007 
ES150010005163  1820   1          129       405
```

y así sucesivamente `cría.2008, prod.2008, tcambio.2008....`

Además me muestra el `warning`:

```
Warning message:
In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
   multiple rows match for camparto=2008: first taken
```

¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que tienes la solución con R base, veamos la alternativa con `dplyr()`, básicamente la mecánica es la misma, generamos un numerador por `id` y sobre ese dato expandimos horizontalmente la información

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(id, días) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n,
              values_from = c(año, prod, cría, tcambio))


# A tibble: 3 x 18
# Groups:   id, días [3]
  id              días año_1 año_2 año_3 año_4 prod_1 prod_2 prod_3 prod_4 cría_1 cría_2 cría_3 cría_4 tcambio_1 tcambio_2 tcambio_3 tcambio_4
  <fct>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 ES150010005163  1820  2007  2008  2009  2010    129    156    157    172      1      2      1      1       405       730      1093      1460
2 ES150010005167  2223  2008  2009  2010    NA    186    167    218     NA      1      1      1     NA       727      1145      1498        NA
3 ES150010005168  1691  2007    NA    NA    NA    116     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA       407        NA        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer no tiene una variable de tiempo, así que tiene que crearlo. Para esto usaría las funciones `rle` y `sequence`. Con esto crearía las veces que se repite el `id`. Pero esto sólo funciona si el vector es `character`. Así que primero tendré que convertir a caracter el vector `id`.

```
datos$id<-as.character(datos$id)
```

Una vez que es caracter, uso las funciones que mencioné.

```
datos$var<-sequence(rle(datos$id)$lengths)
```

Con lo cual, tu dataframe quedaría de esta manera:

```
> datos
              id días  año prod cría tcambio var
1 ES150010005163 1820 2007  129    1     405   1
2 ES150010005163 1820 2008  156    1     730   2
3 ES150010005163 1820 2009  157    2    1093   3
4 ES150010005163 1820 2010  172    1    1460   4
5 ES150010005167 2223 2008  186    1     727   1
6 ES150010005167 2223 2009  167    1    1145   2
7 ES150010005167 2223 2010  218    1    1498   3
8 ES150010005168 1691 2007  116    1     407   1
```

Ahora, se aplica la función `reshape` que estabas usando anteriormente. Pero tienes que definir como tus `idvar` a las variables que se mantendrán, las cuales son `id` y `días`, por último usas la variable de tiempo que creamos `var`. Y listo.

```
reshape(datos, timevar = c("var"),
                   idvar = c("id", "días"),
                   direction = "wide")
```

Este sería el resultado.

```
              id días año.1 prod.1 cría.1 tcambio.1 año.2 prod.2 cría.2 tcambio.2 año.3 prod.3 cría.3 tcambio.3 año.4 prod.4
1 ES150010005163 1820  2007    129      1       405  2008    156      1       730  2009    157      2      1093  2010    172
5 ES150010005167 2223  2008    186      1       727  2009    167      1      1145  2010    218      1      1498    NA     NA
8 ES150010005168 1691  2007    116      1       407    NA     NA     NA        NA    NA     NA     NA        NA    NA     NA
  cría.4 tcambio.4
1      1      1460
5     NA        NA
8     NA        NA
```

Comment: ´Buena solución, solo como comentario secundario, el uso de `rle()` y `sequence()` depende que los datos estén ordenados, que en ejemplo dado lo están, pero no está de más mencionarlo.